# NLog not creating a log file inside AWS ec2 Linux

Tags: asp.net, amazon-ec2, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, nlog

I have a .net core application in AWS ec2 linux and it does NOT create a log file. The application on AWS ec2 linux is published with Deployment Mode: Self-contained and Target Runtime: linux-x64.

I tried it on windows and it does create a log file but somehow it's not working in AWS ec2 linux.

Heres what I did.

- Open ubuntu machine terminal (CLI) and Go to the project directory
- Provide execute permissions: `chmod 777 ./appname`
- Execute application
- `./appname`

**Note:** It displays the Hello World.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var logContext = new LogContextHelper(null, "MBP", "MBP",
        new JObject() {
                    { "ASD", "asd" },
                    { "ZXC", "asd" },
                    { "QWE", "asd" },
                    { "POI", "" }
        }, setAsContextLog: true))
            { }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
        }
        //sample s = new sample("consuna") { objectinitial = "objuna"};


            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

    Here is the NLog.config


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd                NLog.xsd"
          autoReload="true"
          throwExceptions="false"
          internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

        <variable name="myvar" value="myvalue"/>

        <targets>
        <target xsi:type="File" name="fileMBP" fileName="/home/ec2-user/mbpTESTING.log"`enter code here`
              layout="Logger=&quot;MBP API&quot;,
        TimeStamp=&quot;${event-context:item=datetime}&quot;,
        TimeStampMel=&quot;${event-context:item=datetimeMel}&quot;,
        Message=&quot;${message}&quot;,
        Context=&quot;${basedir}&quot;,
        Command=&quot;${event-context:item=command}&quot;,
        ${event-context:item=properties}"
            archiveFileName="/home/ec2-user/MBP.{#}.txt"
            archiveEvery="Day"
            archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
            maxArchiveFiles="7"
            concurrentWrites="true"
            keepFileOpen="false"/>

       </targets>

       <rules>
        <logger name="MBP" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="fileMBP"/>
       </rules>
       </nlog>


        I expect that it will create a log file with logs on it just like on windows.
```

Comment: If the console is working. Then enable `internalLogToConsole="true"` and `internalLogLevel="Info"` and check for errors. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Comment: Btw. the usually reason for NLog not working is because `NLog.config` is not deployed properly. And if no output from NLog InternalLogger in the console after the above change, then it is probably the cause.